# Background location access not declared on google play

Tags: android, yandexmapkit, google-play-console

Если кто сталкивался с проблемой - подскажите, пожалуйста. В приложение использую карту, yandex mapkit. Приложение опубликовал в google play, все было нормально, но через время гугл снял приложение с публикации. Аргументация - Background location access not declared. Я в приложении не использую определение геопозиции в фоне, в манифесте прописал

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
> tools:node="remove"

но в манифеста библиотеки yandex mapkit есть строка

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"

Для корректной работы приложение мне необходима геолокация, показывать положение пользователя и ближайшие парковки рядом с ним.

Пробовал сделать все, как в подсказывают в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61635589/permission-review-google-play-for-access-to-background-location , но в таком случае гугл отвечает

> We detected that your app contains at least one feature that requests access to location in the background, however  your permission declaration form did not reflect this. Please log in to your Play Console to resubmit your location declaration form. You may either remove location in the background from your app or indicate that the usage is in the background

Если я заполняю форму, указываю для чего мне нужно определение геопозиции в "фоне" "хотя я не использую в фоне по факту, только когда приложение запущено" - то мне приходит ответ

> Feature does not meet requirements for background location access
> Based on our review, your declared feature does not meet the requirements for background location access.
> Please remove the background location permission requested and submit an update to your app. When declaring a feature for background location access, please note the following:
> Your selected feature should deliver clear value to the user and be important to the core functionality, or main purpose of the app. Without this core feature, the app is “broken” or rendered unusable.
> You should also consider if users would expect the app to access their location in the background, and if you can deliver the same experience without accessing location in the background.

Написал в support - но они просто молчат. Вдруг кто сталкивался уже с этим и смог решить - подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: почему бы просто не удалить uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION из манифеста?

Comment: android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" в манифесте вообще не прописан. И на всякий случай - добавил uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="remove". При добавилении "tools:node="remove" - удаляется разрешение даже в случае, если это добавлено из манифестов других библиотек. И по факту разрешение это вообще не запрашивается.

Comment: Необходимые разрешения (12)
ИНДИВИДУАЛЬНЫЕ (1)
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ОБЩИЕ (11)
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE, com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE.  разрешения указаны в консоли, как необходимые

Answer (score 0):

Если кому интересен будет ещё этот момент - проблема в sdk yandex mapkik. Яндекс не ответил в поддержке, ничем помочь не смог, но они действительно запускают отслеживание положения в фоне. Есть 2 способа, либо перейти на другие карты, c google картами таких проблем точно не возникнет, либо добавить функцию в фоне, которую получится аргументировать в google. В таком случае приложение вернут в стор, и дальше вопросов возникать не будет.

Comment: Насколько знаю, поддержка рекомендует при использовании LocationManager вызывать у него метод suspend() в обработчике onPause() у активити, а при вызове onResume() у активити звать метод resume(). И вроде как при этом запросов за местоположением в фоне быть не должно. А на текущей версии MapKit 4.1.0 это ещё актуально?